# Autocomplete list from SQLite with criteria

Tags: android, sqlite, autocomplete

Can someone point me to right direction, how to create an adapter for `AutoCompleteTextView`, which would be getting data from `SQLite` DB, using data, which user entered into the text field? I want to use the user-entered data to filter suggestions for autocompletion. I imagine that adapter should always take user-entered data as soon as changes appears and use it for fetching suggestions on-the-fly. Is that possible? So far I've seen many tutorials for autocompletion where static `String` arrays were used, but never seen them build dynamically. Is it possible to do it automatically or I need always fetch `String` array myself and pass as `ArrayList` to adapter on every `AutoCompleteTextView` change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be looking for [`CursorAdapter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html). Use it just like an `ArrayAdapter`, but instead of feeding it with an `ArrayList`, provide a database `Cursor`. Google for `CursorAdapter` and you should get a lot more example codes.